# MySQL join table where second table has at least one NULL field for the key

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables `orders` and `order_items`

The order_items table has a Completion_Date field which is NULL until that item is completed. I only want to return orders with at least one item that has a NULL Completion_Date.

```
SELECT orders.Order_Number
  FROM orders
LEFT JOIN order_items 
   ON (orders.Order_Number = order_items.Order_Number)
WHERE order_items_Completion_Date IS NULL
```

How can I join where there is **at least one** NULL Completion_Date field for the Order_Number key?

Answer (score 1):

You might find that `exists` does a better job for this:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where exists (select 1
              from order_items oi
              where oi.Order_Number = o.Order_Number and
                    oi.Completion_Date is null
             );
```

Although you can also do this with a `join`, that method might result in duplicate rows if an order has more than one item with a `NULL` completion date.

Comment: Thanks, how could I include a count of all the order_items for the Order_Number, not just the ones with NULL Completion_Date?

Comment: @blarg . . . That sounds like a new question to me.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you just have to put the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause like that:

```
SELECT orders.Order_Number
  FROM orders
LEFT JOIN order_items 
   ON (orders.Order_Number = order_items.Order_Number)
   AND order_items_Completion_Date IS NULL
```